# Генерация таблицы в цикле посредством PHP скрипта

Tags: php, html

Всем привет! Господа, уважаемые гуру, подскажите пожалуйста. Есть таблица:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Генерируется всё это дело вот так:

```
<table style="border:1px solid #ccc;width:300px;">
<?php
$t = 0;
$bg = 0;
for($i=0;$i<35;$i++){
    if($bg < 5){
        $bgr = 'fff';
    }else{
        $bgr = 'ccc';
    }
    ?>
    <tr style="background:#<?php echo $bgr; ?>;text-align:center;">
        <?php
        for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){

                ?><td><? echo $t; ?></td><?

            $t++;
        }
        ?>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $bg++;
    if($bg == 10){
        $bg = 0;
    }
}
?>
</table>
```

Как нужно модифицировать вышеуказанный код, что бы добавить к этой таблице сбоку ячейки, объединяющее вертикально 5 горизонтальных генерируемых в цикле. В результате должно получиться вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Никак не могу догнать как это организовать в работающем цикле. Подскажите пожалуйста. Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
for($j=0; $j<3; $j++) {
   if (($i === 0 || $i % 5 === 0) && $j === 0) {
     ?><td rowspan="5"><? echo $letters[$i/5];  ?></td><?
   }?>
   <td>
     <? echo $t; ?>
   </td>
   $t++;
 }
```

Где-нибудь перед первым циклом создайте массив

```
$letters = ['A', 'B', 'C', ...];
```

Comment: Спасибо! Уже что-то: http://i73.fastpic.ru/big/2016/0324/cf/b9e09e728b141752dd1c736651ff04cf.jpg может надо ещё где нибудь исключение воткнуть?

Comment: Сделал вот так, помогло: for($j=0;$j<3;$j++){
   if ($i === 0 || $i % 5 === 0 ) {
    if ($j === 0 ) {
     ?><td rowspan="5">11</td><?
   }}  Скажите, это может быть правильным решением?

Comment: В принципе всё устраивает. Благодарю за наводку!

Comment: @Incognito, да, это правильное решение, т.к. добавлять ячейку нужно только в 0-й колонке, а не во всех.
Рекомендую вам посмотреть в сторону smarty, twig или другого шаблонизатора, т.к. html смешанный с php выглядит ужасно ). Такой код очень сложно поддерживать, а со временем станет невозможно.

Comment: Спасибо! Попробую покопать в сторону Ваших рекомендаций.